# Angular Material Menu

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am new to web programming and working on angular 9 and want to create a sub menu using angular material menu component.

There is no compilation error and the program run successfully, but the sub menu is not working and I cannot understand the reason why.

The code of my component and app.module.ts is given below

**nested-menu-component.html**

```
<p>nested-menu works!</p>
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor] = "menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu= "matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NestedMenuComponent } from './nested-menu/nested-menu.component';  
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NestedMenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatMenuModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```